# Infinite acceleration without loss of energy in a vacuum, gravity-less void?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, acceleration

Suppose we have a void that is free of any other objects or forces, even gravity (impossible I know but hypothetically). If one were to propel an object forward, would that object be able to accelerate infinitely without requiring further addition of energy?

My line of thinking may be totally off, but an object that had energy applied to it loses the energy after work is done right? And when it comes to movement that initial acceleration energy dissipates when it encounters resistance through friction or gravity in a vacuum.

But if one were to remove all external forces aside from the initial burst of energy, that energy would have nowhere else to go, other than to propel the object forward faster and faster?

It’s been awhile since I’ve done calculus and physics so forgive me if I’m missing something ha.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed amount of energy will not lead to an object moving faster and faster. A fixed amount of energy would give the object a fixed velocity and that's that.

A fixed *force* that kept being applied would make the object move faster and faster. But the longer the time interval, the greater the total energy needed to apply that force over that interval. You don't get anything for free.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, energy is conserved. An object could not, without external forces, propel itself faster and faster as this would mean an ever-increasing kinetic energy. The only way to achieve this would be to apply, non-stop, a force that accelerates it. If you do work on a ball and accelerate it, the ball would travel and the same speed once you stop doing work on it. *That kinetic energy* wouldn't have anywhere to go and so it remains constant, as per conservation of energy (and because kinetic energy is the *only* energy).

Answer (score 0):

The resistive force you mentioned here is what provides the deceleration for the body.
So technically without any deceleration(friction, gravity) and no acceleration(other than the initial one provided), the body travels at a constant velocity(provided by the initial acceleration).

You can disprove your statement of increasing velocity as that would lead to an increase in kinetic energy without any change in potential energy(gravitational/any other energy) and hence invalidate conservation of energy.

Also, constant energy(kinetic) won't result in acceleration(change velocity), only changing kinetic energy can result in a change in velocity.

I have made many assumptions to give a simple explanation but hope this helps!